# Stack around variable is corrupted

Tags: c++, stack, stack-corruption

I know this topic has a lot of questions, but they all seem specific to the code.

I have this function -

```
Point2 ITCS4120::operator* (const Matrix3x3& m, const Point2& p) {
   Point2 result;
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
       result[i] = (m[i][0]*p[0]) + (m[i][1]*p[1]) + (m[i][2]);
       }
   return result; //error here
   }
```

It gives me an error on the return statement saying "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'result' was corrupted."

I cannot see anything wrong with that function. The Matrix3x3's array is just -

```
float array[3][3];
```

and the Point2's array is

```
float array [2];
```

Both the Matrix3x3 and Point2 classes have this code -

```
/** Write access for element in row [i] */
inline Scalar* operator[](int i) {return array[i];}
/** Read access for element in row [i] */
inline const Scalar* operator[](int i)const {return array[i];}
```

This code was given to me and I had some previous homework to do arithmetic with points, matricis, and vectors. My code passed all the tests so I assumed my Point2 ITCS4120::operator* (const Matrix3x3& m, const Point2& p) code was correct. But maybe I need to use the [] operators differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems your point contains two `float`s but you are writing to three.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I just needed another pair of eyes.